# May I use foreach in this case? How to WriteLine string "cool"?

Tags: c#

I learn C# and make the code. How to print word "cool" with foreach operator:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string [ ] arr = {"a", "c", "a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "l"};
   string sum = ""; 

   foreach (string x in arr)
   {
      sum += x * 2;
   }
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

I cannot use `x * 2` , if I use only `sum += x`, Output is "acaoaoal". How to receive output "cool" by using foreach?

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i += 2)
{
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

You need for loop and start it from `i=1` with step `+2`.

If your assignment is to use foreach you need to add another variable as counter, and you need to check it if it is even number.

```
int count = -1;
foreach(string x in arr)
{
   count++;
   if(count % 2 == 0)
      continue;

   sum += x;
}
```

Be aware if the string array is too big you should use `StringBuilder` for concatenation of strings.

How to do it with linq:

```
var result = arr.Select((x, i) => i % 2 == 1 ? x:"").Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", result));
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be easier if you use a for loop with step instead of for each.

```
for (var i = 1; i  < 8; i += 2) {
  sum += strArr [i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

forEach loop doesn't a have counter. You should explicitly specify your own:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string [ ] arr = {"a", "c", "a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "l"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int index = 0;
    foreach (string element in arr)
    {
        if(index % 2 != 0)
           sb.Append(element);

        index++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
Array.ForEach(arr, x => { if(Array.IndexOf(arr,x) % 2 != 0) output.Append(x); });
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. It is simply interesting how foreach works. I see -  It is nesessary to build new counters. And I do not understand why foreach elements should be "string" when we count chars. On my opinion it is like indexers. But I have to determine type of counter depend on elements type.

Comment: Probably because a lot of people frown on code-only answers. You might want to include some text that describes this solution and provides some more information.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
string[] arr = { "a", "c", "a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "l" };
string sum = "";

foreach (string x in arr.Where((c, n) => n % 2 == 1))
{
    sum += x;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

You can even write it as:

```
string[] arr = { "a", "c", "a", "o", "a", "o", "a", "l" };
string sum = String.Join("", arr.Where((c, n) => n % 2 == 1));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```